# Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, redis

After installing Redis on ubuntu 16.04, I am unable to activate the service. When I check it with `sudo systemctl status redis` it shows me the below error:

```
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2019-06-12 12:34:59 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 16672 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 16670 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 16670 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jun 12 12:34:59 ip- systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 12 12:34:59 ip- systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Jun 12 12:34:59 ip- systemd[1]: redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 12 12:34:59 ip- systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Jun 12 12:34:59 ip- systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 12 12:34:59 ip- systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

I have tried restarting the redis server `sudo systemctl restart redis` but it didn't worked.

Also tried changing the owner of redis directory with below code:

`sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis`

`sudo systemctl restart redis`

but it won't work either.

Please help me to resolve this issue.